# border-radius and background-color conflict in css

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

See this [JSFIDDLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9nYJ.png). I am using jqueryUI datepicker.
As you can see selected date looks like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
  .ui-state-highlight,
  .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight,
  .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
    border: 0;
    background: red;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
  }
```

I am looking for a solution which makes `td` looks like this.

[image]

***Keep in mind `background-color` and `border-color` is not same.***

Note: dont suggest to use image sprite etc.

Please give an answer only with css.

Comment: do you need this?:  `border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;`

Comment: no it wont work. try on fiddle itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally done this only with css, see [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6qLmnkac/9/) here
One need to play a bit with `position` and `after`.

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

```css
.ui-state-highlight,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
td {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1111;
}
a.ui-state-default.ui-state-highlight:after {
  content: "";
  background: green;
  height: 23px;
  width: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  right: 0;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="demo">

    <p>Date:
      <input id="datepicker" type="text">
    </p>

  </div>
  <!-- End demo -->

  <div style="display: none;" class="demo-description">
    <p>The datepicker is tied to a standard form input field. Focus on the input (click, or use the tab key) to open an interactive calendar in a small overlay. Choose a date, click elsewhere on the page (blur the input), or hit the Esc key to close. If
      a date is chosen, feedback is shown as the input's value.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- End demo-description -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no conflict between border-radius and background-color. below example border-radius implement at a tag  and you want to add the background in td so both element are separate like below :

```
 <a class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight" href="#">19</a>
<td class=" ui-datepicker-days-cell-over  ui-datepicker-today" onclick="DP_jQuery_1484829217856.datepicker._selectDay('#datepicker',0,2017, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight" href="#">19</a></td>
```

so where you want to override the css need to add !impotent in the css. below i have updated the code at JSFIDDLE. may help you.

solved link :  http://jsfiddle.net/6qLmnkac/7/

Comment: in mine case bg-color of `a` and `td` is different. so it mean `border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;` this is not what am looking for.

Comment: Please check this URL . it will be same as you want : http://jsfiddle.net/6qLmnkac/7/

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6qLmnkac/8/) - if you have no problem with `td{position:relative}`

[image]

Comment: how will it help. plz elaborate as an answer.

Comment: did you see the fiddle?

Comment: fiddle is not matching my requirement. it just have a rounded corned no `bg-color` on top and right corner.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a different background colour which is why `border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;` doesn't work for you. One solution is to select the background and change its gradient.
I have used http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator to generate the color-gradient.

```css
.ui-state-highlight,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
  border: 0;
  
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  
}
.ui-datepicker td {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0px;
}

//Create the gradient for the td here-- only for the selected date
//At the end date, reverse the gradient and it will look almost like the picture you shared. 
 .ui-datepicker-today {
 background: rgba(105,84,68,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(105,84,68,1) 47%, rgba(173,217,120,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(47%, rgba(105,84,68,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(173,217,120,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(105,84,68,1) 47%, rgba(173,217,120,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(105,84,68,1) 47%, rgba(173,217,120,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(105,84,68,1) 47%, rgba(173,217,120,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(105,84,68,1) 47%, rgba(173,217,120,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#695444', endColorstr='#add978', GradientType=1 );
 }
```

Comment: Try pasting the css in your original file. It's not running here coz I did not include html and js in the snippet.